# RAII для WinAPI с учетом 64-битной архитектуры Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, x86-64, raii

Постепенно мигрирую с C на C++ и 32- на 64-битную Windows. При написании программ с использованием WinAPI возник ряд вопросов, объединенных одной общей темой - RAII. Так как я изучаю C++ всего третий месяц, а понять некоторые тонкости вышеозвученной идиомы программирования все же хотелось уже сейчас (хотя бы на базовом уровне), решила задать вопрос знающим в том людям.
Как выглядит в моем представлении шаблон RAII для большинства API функций (с учетом 64-битных версий Windows)?

```
// обращаться к функциям освобождения ресурсов по адресу
typedef VOID (WINAPI *PFNCLEANUP)(UINT_PTR);

template<class T, PFNCLEANUP pfn, UINT_PTR inval = NULL>
class CResFree {
private:
  UINT_PTR m_res;
public:
  CResFree() { m_res = inval; } // конструктор по умолчанию
  // этот конструктор задает значение
  CResFree(T t) : m_res(reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(t)) {}
  // здесь реализуется логика освобождения ресурсов
  ~CResFree() { Cleanup(); }
  // вспомогательная функция класса, позволяет установить
  // является ли ресурс валидным или нет
  BOOL IsValid() const { return (m_res != inval); }
  // если нужно переназначить данные нашего ресурса
  T operator=(T t) {
    Cleanup(); // освободили ресурс
    m_res = reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(t); // задали новое значение
    return (*this); // вернули данные
  }
  // вернуть значение
  operator T() { return reinterpret_cast<T>(m_res); }
  // собственно функция очистки
  void Cleanup() {
    if (IsValid()) {
      pfn(m_res); // освободили ресурс
      m_res = inval; // потерли данные
    }
  }
};
```

Код я достаточно плотно закомментировала, так что если я в чем-то неправа, матерые кодеры C++ мне сразу укажут на ошибки. В чем состоит мой вопрос? Прежде всего насколько корректно мое представление о RAII? На мой взгляд все достаточно логично и каких-либо дополнительных перегрузок или еще чего-то не требуется. Но, повторюсь, это только на мой взгляд. Хотелось бы конструктивной критики.
Также у меня есть вопрос как упростить объявление типа в последствии, так как на данный момент эти объявления относительно кода выше у меня выглядят так:

```
typedef CResFree<HANDLE, reinterpret_cast<PFNCLEANUP>(CloseHandle), reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)> CCloseFile;
```

В C можно использовать макросы, но мне часто доводилось слышать что макросы в C++ использовать не стоит, лучше использовать встраиваемые (*inline*) функции. Однако встраиваемые функции жрут память как не в себя. Может тогда есть более лучший вариант RAII вообще, скажем, через лямбда?

Comment: Для RAII можно использовать блок SEH __finally в сишном стиле. Зачем обязательно использовать C++? Накручивать слои C++ вокруг WinAPI это изврат.

Comment: Тут четыре основные проблемы - масса ненужных кастов, отсутствие копирующих / перемещающих конструкторов (правило 0 / 3 / 5), наличие implicit конструктора и оператора приведения типа, отсутствие проверки значения, возвращаемого освобождающей функцией (`CloseHandle` возвращает `BOOL`, а с таким кастом получится неопределенное поведение). *"Однако встраиваемые функции жрут память как не в себя."* inline ничего не говорит о том, встраивается функция или нет.

Comment: @VTT, можно более развернуто с примерами, чтобы было понятней?

Comment: @typemoon, изврат - это как раз `__try..__finally`. Как вы себе представляете, например, заголовочный файл с такой конструкцией?

Comment: Не пытаюсь посягнуть на святое (это я про RAII), но может не стоит так уж стремиться быть на переднем крае? Вполне возможно обернуть все ресурсы WinAPI в шаблонные классы, но повысит ли это качество программы в плане наглядности и сопровождаемости кода? Оберните в обычные нешаблонные классы сложные вещи, которые вы реально используете - файлы, пайпы, сокеты, что-то еще. А мелочи проще использовать как есть. Печально, что вместо нормального finally комитет предпочел сделать фетиш из RAII, но что тут сделаешь.

Comment: @freim, печально то, что ничего по существу в ответ я так и не услышала: ни аргументов, ни примеров, разве что _VTT_ ещё что-то мимоходом путное написал, но не дал развернутого пояснения. Фетишизм здесь не при чем, мне хочется разобраться в сути RAII как такового, как его грамотно реализовать и т.д. Но раз сообщество пребывает в каком-то анабиозе, высказываясь главным образом не по существу, думаю мне предстоит самой разбираться что к чему. Жаль, а я считала что здесь не гонятся за накруткой репутации и всегда говорят только по делу.

Comment: Ну вот вам по делу - что произойдет с управляемым ресурсом при передаче вашей переменной в функцию, допустим? (а про фетишизм было адресовано не вам вообще-то)

Comment: Использование `NULL` в качестве значения по умолчанию для целочисленного параметра шаблона не допускается. Исправьте на `0`.

Comment: Вот еще по делу: Явно недостает перемещающего конструктора. А оператор присваивания имеет смысл заменить на традиционный [copy&swap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/2752075) (с передачей параметра по значению).

Comment: @freim Вместо finally у нас по большому счету scope guard'ы (из boost или самописные).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, в теории все выглядит замечательно, но в реальной жизни время жизни ресурса может слабо коррелировать с блочной структурой. Все-таки finally небходим. Впрочем, здесь это офтоп, да и вообще какой смысл обсуждать то, на что невозможно повлиять.