# Умные указатели для функций открывающих объект, но возвращающих булев тип

Tags: c++, winapi, raii

Обычно пользуюсь умными указателями для того, чтобы избежать проблем с высвобождением ресурсов. Например, в случае с *LoadLibrary* можно поступить так:

```
auto my_instance = std::unique_ptr<HMODULE, function<void(HMODULE*)>>
                    (new HMODULE(LoadLibrary(_T("my_library.dll"))), [](HMODULE* instance){ FreeLibrary(*instance); });
```

Собственно, вопрос: а как нужно (и возможно ли вообще?) запилить указатель для, скажем, *OpenClipboard*?

Comment: Да у буферов нет дескрипторов наподобие HMODULE/HWND...   
Поэтому я бы не стал выносить буфер в отдельный класс, а сделал бы набор функций `get_buffer`, `set_buffer` и контроль по открытию/закрытию буферов через функции винапи можно возложить на эти функции.  
Например если функция чтения открывает буфер, то гарантированно должна закрыть его за собой. Сделать это можно через обычные if-else или через __try / __finally (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/try-finally-statement?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Как вариант, можно взять boost scope guard или что-то подобное.

Answer (score 3):

`std::unique_ptr` можно приспособить к работе с посторонними хэндлами через указание пользовательского "удалятеля". В классе "удалятеля" должен присутствовать вложенный тип `pointer`, описывающий используемый тип хэндла и выражение `pointer()` должно описывать невалидный хэндл.

В вашем случае хэндла как такового нет, а есть лишь флаг успешности операции `OpenClipboard` типа `BOOL`, который и является неким огрубленным "черно-белым" хэндлом вида "да/нет". Выражение `BOOL()`, к счастью, в данном случае описывает именно "невладение", т.е. неуспешное завершение `OpenClipboard`.

Поэтому без особых усилий получаем

```
#include <memory>
#include <windows.h>

struct ClipboardDeleter
{
  using pointer = BOOL;

  void operator ()(BOOL del) const
  {
    if (del)
      CloseClipboard();
  }
};

int main() 
{
  std::unique_ptr<BOOL, ClipboardDeleter> guard(OpenClipboard(NULL));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Такой подход имеет право на жизнь, но это все же не лучший вариант. Если уж хочется обернуть все WinAPI, то лучше использовать шаблонный класс-обертку. Примерно как в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/918897/raii-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-winapi-%D1%81-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-64-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-windows). Там, правда, сделано неправильно, потому что надо решить вопрос владения, и вообще сделать потщательнее, но сам подход верный. `OpenClipboard` в такой класс тоже впишется без проблем.