# Лямбда в умных указателях вместо функторов

Tags: c++, winapi, unique-ptr, raii

Пытаюсь понять принцип оборачивания WinAPI'шных функций в *unique_ptr*. Допустим, нужно мне вызвать *CreateFile*, чтобы не заморачиваться с закрытием хэндла, планирую последний запихнуть в *unique_ptr*. Как узнать, что получаемый хэндл валидный и возможно ли обойтись без функтора, вместо него использовать лямбда с *CloseHandle* для закрытия хэндла? Словом, как на примере *CreteFile* все это грамотно реализовать?

Answer (score 3):

(Аналогичный вопрос [Умные указатели для функций открывающих объект, но возвращающих булев тип](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/923795/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF))

Не совсем понятно, при чем тут лямбда. Лямбды тут будет мало.

Чтобы использовать "хэндл" вместо указателя придется определять свой deleter с вложенным типом `pointer`. Для тех функций, которые используют нулевое значение хэндла для обозначения отсутствия ресурса (т.е. значение `HANDLE()`, которое дает `true` при сравнении с `nullptr`) , все просто

```
struct HandleDeleter
{
  using pointer = HANDLE;

  void operator ()(HANDLE h) const
    { SomeReleaseResourceFunction(h); }
};
```

Какая функция будет выступать в качестве `SomeReleaseResourceFunction` зависит от природы вашего хэндла. См. например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/948919/182825

А вот с `CreateFile` ситуация иная - она для обозначения неуспешного завершения использует значение `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, которое не совпадает со значением `HANDLE()` и не дает равенства с `nullptr`. Наивный вариант реализации в этом случае может выглядеть так

```
struct CloseHandleDeleter
{
  using pointer = HANDLE;

  void operator ()(HANDLE h) const
  { 
    if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      CloseHandle(h);
  }
};
```

Но в этом случае проверки типа `if (file)` не будут работать правильно. Чтобы победить эту проблему придется еще завернуть `HANDLE` в какой-то класс-оболочку.

Для случаев, когда отсутствие ресурса обозначается значением `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, правильным вариантом будет что-то вроде

```
class NullableHANDLE
{
public:
  NullableHANDLE() = default;
  NullableHANDLE(std::nullptr_t) {}
  NullableHANDLE(HANDLE h) : h(h) {}

  operator HANDLE() const
    { return h; }

  friend bool operator ==(const NullableHANDLE &lhs, const NullableHANDLE &rhs)
    { return lhs.h == rhs.h; }
  friend bool operator !=(const NullableHANDLE &lhs, const NullableHANDLE &rhs)
    { return lhs.h != rhs.h; }

private:
  HANDLE h = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
};

struct CloseHandleDeleter
{
  using pointer = NullableHANDLE;

  void operator ()(pointer p) const
    { CloseHandle(p); }
};

void foo() 
{
  std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, CloseHandleDeleter> file(CreateFile("vasya.txt", GENERIC_READ, 
    0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL));

  if (file)
    /* Файл открыт успешно */;
    ReadFile(file.get(), ...);

  /* Здесь файл "закроется сам" */
}
```

Comment: Плохая практика передавать напрямую значение, а не указатель на значение  
  `std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, CloseHandleDeleter> file(CreateFile("vasya.txt", GENERIC_READ, 
    0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL));` Только по счастливой случайности HANDLE оказался void* хотя тут скорее ожидается HANDLE* и хорошо,что он совпал по размерности.

Comment: @Andrey Sv: Нет, ни в коем случае. Никакого "указателя" `unique_ptr` не ожидает. `unique_ptr` работает именно с *хэндлами*. Классический указатель - это лишь частный случай *хэндла*. Кастомный делетер и вложенный в него переопределяемый тип `pointer` как раз и предназначен для того, чтобы приспосабливать `unique_ptr` для работы с другими типами хэндлов. Никаких "случайностей" в вышеприведенном коде нет, никакого `void *` нигде не фигурирует и никаких совпадений по размерности нигде не требуется. При чем здесь `void *` - мне не ясно.

Comment: Конструктор `unique_ptr` в моем коде ожидает значения именно типа `CloseHandleDeleter::pointer`,  то есть именно `HANDLE`, а не `HANDLE *` как вы неправильно предположили.

Comment: Т.е. если хандл будет  типа long long  в 32 битной ситеме где указатель 32 бита, то все будет хорошо? Или мы говорим только о Windows  HANDLE? Котрому никто не запрещает стать больше размером, так как он является частью Windows API  а не STL.

Comment: @Andrey Sv: Я еще раз повторяю: данный код никак не зависит от размера или природы типа  `HANDLE` и будет корректно работать при любом размере `HANDLE`. Никаких завязок на "32 бита" и "размер указателя" в этом коде нет даже отдаленно. Код совершенно портабелен. `HANDLE` может быть хоть 256-битным значением, хоть псевдонимом для `std::string`. Это все никак не влияет на корректность кода.

Comment: Да, вижу. Весь фокус в `using pointer = NullableHANDLE;` в функторе. Но, как по мне, код с лямбдой гораздо короче и вполне безопасен и эффективен. При этом еще остается возможность работать с хандлом напрямую.

Comment: @Andrey Sv: Да, все дело именно в `using pointer = NullableHANDLE;`, Однако вся эта возня с `NullableHANDLE` нужна только из-за того, что "старые" функции WinAPI используют ненулевой `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. Для функций, использующих нулевой `HANDLE`, так мучаться не надо - достаточно первого варианта.

Comment: По большому счету первый вариант это и есть лямбда, только с добавлением типа указателя.

Comment: @Andrey Sv: Да, ценное наблюдение. Было бы удобно, если бы С++ лямбда-выражения позволяли бы еще как-то добавлять типы-псевдонимы внутрь генерируемого лямбда-класса. Чтобы не нужно было выписывать целый класс, который по сути является просто лямбдой. Но такой возможности в языке нет.

Comment: Скорее, наверное, в параметр шаблона добавить бы тип указателя а не заморачиваться с его определением через функтор.

Answer (score -3):

> Как узнать, что получаемый хэндл валидный и возможно ли обойтись без
>   функтора, вместо него использовать лямбда с CloseHandle для закрытия
>   хэндла?

Простой ответ на простой вопрос, да, можно. Пример ниже.

```
        {
            auto del = [](HANDLE* h) { 
                if (h && *h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) // Проверка на валидность
                ::CloseHandle(*h); 
            };
            HANDLE h = ::CreateFile(L"test.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL); 
            std::unique_ptr < HANDLE, decltype(del)> file(&h, del); // Закрытие произойдет при уничтожении объекта 

         // Дальше можно использовать чистый HANDLE
         if (!::WriteFile(h, ...) )
            return; // Файл закроется корректно так как будет разрушен объект file и соответсвенно будет выполнена лямбда del

          ...

         if (!::ReadFile(h, ...) )
            return; // Файл закроется

          ...

// Здесь также файл будет закрыт
        }
```

Что касается использования указателя на HANDLE, то в пределах одного блока в этом нет ничего страшного. Мало того указатель более информативен,чем продублированный `HANDLE` в `unique_ptr` так как он указывает на единственную переменную а не дублирует ее.  Что помимо прочего освобождает от необходимости полностью перегружать `HANDLE` как объект, чтобы его можно было безопасно использовать. Первоначальная цель это соблюдение RAII, которая в данном случае полностью обеспечивается. При этом замечания о том, а что если я захочу вернуть другой `unique_ptr` с этим указателем за пределы блока являются абсолютно бессмысленными, так как файл уже будет закрыт и зачем его невалидный хандлер за пределами блока непонятно, цель ведь закрыть файл и освободить ресурсы именно в пределах блока. Это кстати просто вариант некорректного использования `unique_ptr` аналогичен присвоению одного и того же указателя двум объектам `unique_ptr`. Категорически не рекомендую дублировать `unique_ptr` с тем же указателем, а уж тем более отправлять указатель на локальную переменную за пределы блока с `unique_ptr` или без него.

Если есть необходимость использовать чистые API функции и при этом нужна поддержка RAII без написания собственных оберток API, то лямбда в компании с `unique_ptr` вполне с этим справится.

Что касается собственных оберток API, то не рекомендую изобретать велосипед, а использовать готовые библиотеки классов типа MFC, QT или тот же STL в чистом виде. Что повысит безопасность кода и его переносимость.

Comment: ... и получаем `unique_ptr`, который содержит указатель на локальную переменную `h`! Как только `h` прекратит свое существование, все накроется медным тазом.

Comment: @AnT `unique_ptr` в той же области видимости, и `h` прекратит свое существование после вызова `del`. Здесь нет никакой неопределенности.

Comment: *Этот* `unique_ptr` действительно прекратит свое существование. Но это однако никак не запрещает нам переместить его содержимое в другой `unique_ptr`. `unique_ptr`, например, можно вернуть из функции или присвоить (перемещающе) другому `unique_ptr` из охватывающей области видимости. Это совершенно штатное использование `unique_ptr`. В исходном вопросе не ни слова о том, что данный `unique_ptr` будет использоваться лишь как `scoped_ptr`.

Comment: @AnT Речь идет о данном конкретном коде и в нем все корректно не так ли?

Comment: Не понял. Я же написал выше. Как можно говорить, корректно в этом коде нем все или не корректно, если не видно, что происходит с указателем `file` дальше? По вашему коду невозможно сказать, возникнет ли такая неприятная ситуация, как описал, или нет.

Comment: @AnT В данном коде с объектом file ничего не происходит, это ведь очевидно. Считайте, что за ним стоит скобка и конец программы. Все остальное это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Сейчас да. А потом приходит оптимизационный проход компилятора, выполняет агрессивное встраивание функций по месту вызова и начинает перетасовывать несвязанные между собой команды для оптимального использования регистров и кэша. В результате перед работой с умным указателем вполне может оказаться вызов функции, перезаписывающий «хвост» стека. Или не перезаписывающий — при неопределённом поведении всё зависит от версии компилятора, флагов компиляции и всего исходного кода cpp-файла (или всей программы, если включён LTO). Так что ваше предположение — это бомба замедленного действия. // cc: @AnT

Comment: @Arhad Вообще это обусловлено стандартом и никак не зависит от компилятора или оптимизации.

Comment: Вопрошающий ничего не говорил о сценариях использования умного указателя. Возможно, он хранит дескрипторы как поля класса и не хочет писать типовой код в деструкторе и обработчике исключений конструктора.

Comment: @Arhad Вопрошающий, по моему, задал вполне конкретный вопрос без каких либо "возможно": WinAPI, unique_ptr, lambda, на что я и дал ответ. Дополнительные пояснения сделаны по замечаниям комментирующих. Что конкретно Вас смущает в ответе?