# RAII для параметра-дескриптора

Tags: c++, winapi, unique-ptr, raii

В [этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/925035/%D0%9B%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2) уже рассматривалась техника оборачивания WinAPI функций в `unique_ptr`, однако у меня возник вопрос как это должно реализовываться в функциях, возвратом которых является статус операции, а открываемый дескриптор указывается одним из параметров? К примеру, возьмем `RegOpenKeyEx`, как к данной функции применить аналогичный подход?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/cregkey-class?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

1. Сначала отдельно вызвать `RegOpenKeyEx`, получить результат, а уже потом "передать его на сохранение" в `unique_ptr`. Получится не совсем RAII, но если между получением дескриптора и передачей его в `unique_ptr` не выбрасывается исключений, то цель RAII не нарушается

   ```
   HKEY hkey{};
   RegOpenKeyEx(..., &hkey);
   std::unique_ptr<HKEY, HKEYCloser> unique_hkey(hkey);
   ```

   Это при желании можно записать и через оператор "запятая"

   ```
   HKEY hkey{};
   std::unique_ptr<HKEY, HKEYCloser> unique_hkey((RegOpenKeyEx(..., &hkey), hkey));
   ```
2. Написать свою-функцию обертку для `RegOpenKeyEx`, которая будет именно *возвращать* результат через возвращаемое значение. (Те же замечания.)
3. Еще как-то...

Применение `std::unique_ptr` с системными хэндлам действительно сводится скорее к роли RAII-guard, а не к полноценному smart pointer. Т.е. задача RAII-guard состоит лишь в том, чтобы предотвратить утечку ресурса, а не в том, чтобы целиком подменить собой сам хэндл. Работать c хэндлом именно через `std::unique_ptr` будет действительно неудобно, как правильно заметил @VTT в комментариях. Для локальной работы лучше просто вычитывать из него хэндл и работать с хэндлом напрямую.

Comment: А примеры? Я вообще склонна к тому, чтобы написать класс вроде SafeRegKey, а открытый дескриптор высвобождать в деструкторе класса.

Comment: @Аделина *написать класс вроде SafeRegKey* - а это на самом деле хорошая идея. Когда нельзя вызвать методы оборачиваемого класса через `operator ->` и приходится его куда-то передавать, то работа с `unique_ptr` становится крайне неудобной. А специализированный класс-обертка позволит также инкапсулировать работу (особенно проверку ошибок) всяких низкоуровневых функций WinAPI. В качестве примера можно поглядеть такие обертки из boost.asio.