# как правильно привернуть HBITMAP к make_unique вместе с deleter'ом

Tags: c++, winapi, smart-pointer

Как правильно привернуть HBITMAP к make_unique вместе с deleter'ом, под deleter'ом подразумевается вызов DeleteObject(..). VS ругается по всякому на мои конструкции :)

Заранее спасибо за пример.

Comment: Так вроде как `make_unique` не принимает deleter. Наверное, самое логичное - адаптер написать.

Comment: Да, а ведь точно, к сожалению, нет способа указать удаление в std :: make_unique. Ушел крутить unique_ptr..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В такой ситуации, вместо того, чтобы лезть в детали реализации виндовсовких хендлов и вытаскивать на поверхность тот факт, что хендлы на самом деле являются указателями, правильнее было бы приспособить `std::unique_ptr` для работы с обобщенным хэндлом. `std::unique_ptr` предоставляет вам все необходимые для этого средства.

По аналогии с [Лямбда в умных указателях вместо функторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/925035/%D0%9B%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2/925079#925079), напишите свой удалятель

```
struct GdiHandleDeleter
{
  using pointer = HGDIOBJ;

  void operator ()(HGDIOBJ h) const
    { DeleteObject(h); }
};
```

и используйте его потом в `std::unique_ptr`

```
using hbmp_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<HBITMAP, GdiHandleDeleter>;
hbmp_unique_ptr ptr(CreateBitmap(...));
```

При таком удалятеле, однако, `ptr.get()` будет возвращать `HGDIOBJ`, а не `HBITMAP`. Если для вас критично сохранение разделения типов между `HBITMAP`, `HBRUSH` и т.д., то лучше генерировать свой удалятель для каждого типа GDI объекта.

---

Использование `std::make_unique` тут неуместно, ибо `std::make_unique` всегда создает хранимый объект через вызов `new`. Вам это здесь ни к чему.

Comment: Отлично, второй вариант, вот только кажется проверка на NULL лишняя, вроде unique_ptr не вызывает deleter при нулевом значении.. или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @NewView: Да, верно. Убрал. Там уместнее `assert`, а не проверка.

Answer (score 0):

Как верно подметил @Harry, `make_unique` не имеет настраиваемого deleter'а.
По этому прикручиваем к типу `unique_ptr`:

```
struct HBMPFree
{
    void operator()(HBITMAP hbmp) const noexcept { DeleteObject(hbmp); }
};
using hbmp_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<HBITMAP__, HBMPFree>;

auto hbmp = hbmp_unique_ptr(GetHbmpFunction());
if (!hbmp.get())
{
   /// error
}
HBITMAP phbmp = static_cast<HBITMAP>(hbmp.get());
```

Comment: Что такое `HBITMAP__` и зачем он здесь???

Comment: Это то из чего делается ссылочный HBITMAP с помощью typedef, а зачем так, лучше спросить у авторов из ms

Comment: Это классно, но зачем он понадобился *вам* в вашем коде?

Comment: Не соображу смысл подколки :) как тип вероятно, который принимается вhbmp_unique_ptr, если написать void, то будет ругань.

Comment: Ым... Нет никакой "подколки". У вас везде в приведенном коде используется `HBITMAP`, `HBITMAP` и `HBITMAP`. А здесь вдруг ни с того ни с сего влез какой-то `HBITMAP__`. Вопрос: почему и зачем? Почему не `HBITMAP` и тут тоже?

Comment: По тому что нужен не ссылочный тип. Это и есть HBITMAP__ , по тому как: `typedef HBITMAP__ *HBITMAP;` Вероятно можно было так: `<*HBITMAP,..` но мы не ищем лёгких путей ☺

Comment: А, вот оно что... Нет, это делается не так. Правильный подход: определять свой deleter со своим обобщенным типом "указателя". Я показывал здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/925079/182825 и здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/923967/182825, как это делается. В вашем случае все проще, т.к. невалидным значением хэндла является `NULL`, а не `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`

Comment: Спасибо, смотрю

Comment: Еще раз: вам не нужны все эти навороты из первой ссылки, ибо там они обусловлены особенностью функции `CreateFile`, которая возвращает `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, а не `NULL` в случае ошибки. В вашем же случае достаточно будет простого deleter-а.

Comment: Да, да, как раз первый пост досмотрел, ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: `HBITMAP` не обязательно объявлен как `HBITMAP__ *`, результат вызова `DeleteObject` надо обязательно проверять! Например, если битмап выбран в контекст устройства, то попытка его удалить может закончится неудачей. Вообще `unique_ptr` не особо хорошо подходит для управления дескрипторами.

Comment: @VTT Возможно он не везде так объявлен, что само по себе странно, но на момент компиляции на целевой машине вроде совпадает :) можно и переделать для совместимости на `*HBITMAP`. А вот что можно предложить вместо `unique_ptr` для таких целей?

Comment: Лучше использовать специальный класс. С кастомизацией возможностей для разных видов дескрипторов.

Comment: `make_unique` *позволяет* вам настаивать deleter: непрямым способом, через специализацию  `std::default_delete`. Проблема с `make_unique` не в этом, а в том, что `make_unique` всегда выделает хранимый ресурс через `new`.