# Не получается обернуть HANDLE в std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, winapi, stl, raii

Появилось желание обернуть в RAII классы ряд объектов из WinAPI (хендлы, сертификаты и т.д.) Самым очевидным решением оказались умные указатели, однако с ними возникла проблема следующего характера: deleter для них нельзя передавать в качестве параметра шаблона, нужно передавать в конструктор при создании, что очень неудобно в повседневном использовании, и не позволяет сделать alias (using unique_handle = std::unique_ptr<..>). Нашел на просторах интернета примитивное решение для HANDLE:

```
class SafeHandle
    : public std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type,void(*)(HANDLE)>
{
  public:
    SafeHandle(HANDLE handle)
        : unique_ptr( handle, &SafeHandle::close )
    {
    }
    operator HANDLE()
    {
      return get();
    }
    const bool valid() const
    {
      return ( get() != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE );
    }
  private:
    static void close( HANDLE handle )
    {
      if ( handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        CloseHandle( handle );
    }
};
```

Данный класс работает как ожидается, однако писать подобную обертку на каждый чих тоже крайне неудобно. Попробовал обобщить найденное решение через шаблоны следующим образом:

```
template <typename T>
class Unique
    : public std::unique_ptr<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type, void(*)(T)>
{
  public:
      Unique(T res) 
      : std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<T>>(res, &Unique::close)
    {
    }
    operator T()
    {
      return std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<T>>::get();
    }
    const bool valid() const
    {
      return true; // Не имплементировал, планируется также передать через шаблон
    }
  private:
    static void close(T res)
    {
        // Здесь планируется сделать вызов функтора, передаваемого через шаблон
    }
};
```

При компиляции данного кода получаю 2 ошибки:

```
error C2512: 'std::unique_ptr<void,void (__cdecl *)(HANDLE)>::unique_ptr': no appropriate default constructor available
error C2614: 'Unique<HANDLE>': illegal member initialization: 'unique_ptr' is not a base or member
```

Данные ошибки недвусмысленно намекают, что проблема в наследовании, а именно, что происходит не вызов конструктора базового класса, а что-то другое. В первоначальном коде таких проблем не было, и я полагаю, что накосячил с шаблонами (не силен в них). 
Каким образом я могу достичь желаемого результата?

Comment: указатель на функцию не может быть инициализирован указателем на  функцию_член  Unique::close

Comment: Вы занимаетесь ерундой. Достаточно определить правильный класс deleter и указать его в качестве параметра шаблона. Все ваши трудности - из-за того, что вы пытаетесь использовать обычный указатель на функцию в качестве deleter. Из-за того, что вы хотите сделать `unique_ptr` для `HANDLE` с `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` задача несколько усложняется, но все равно решаема. См. по ссылкам:

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/925035/%D0%9B%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/948762/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-hbitmap-%d0%ba-make-unique-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81-deleter%d0%be%d0%bc/948919#948919

Comment: Ссылки помогли, спасибо.

Comment: В коде как минимум ошибка из-за использования `std::remove_pointer<T>` вместо `typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type` или `std::remove_pointer_t<T>`